# Google Drive revokes my token

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am new to google drive and started with the tutorial [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java). 
After numerous attampts I run the program successfully. 
However I had permission and authorisation problems when I was trying to delete files.

```
Drive service = getDriveService();
service.files().delete("FileId").execute();
```

So I decide to change the URL in the client_secret.json,

From: `"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"`

To: `"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"`

in the hope that I would now get the permission to delete files. However after executing the program again I didn't get the authorization tab of the internet browser like before.

As an example of the mentioned tab, here an image from google playground:

[image: asking for permissions in browser]

That's the reason why I delted the connection from my app to google drive website:

[image]

In addition i recreated also the client_secret.json file. However when I now execute the program I get only this error, independent what I am doing.

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Token has been revoked."
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at main.java.DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

So the two questions are what should i do to get the tutorial running again and how to set the permissions so that i can delete files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I find out the problem:
I had to delete the directory "user.home/.credentials/drive-api-quickstart".
After that I can give the program the authorisation, which it needs.
Hope that someone will help this post ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different case. After getting the example in the [Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) to work a few months ago, I got the following error today when rerunning it.

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request 
{ 
  "error" : "invalid_grant", 
  "error_description" : "Bad Request" 
}
```

Since the tokens were stored in `TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH ("tokens")`, the token stored there probably became invalid. Deleting directory `tokens` allowed me to once again get the browser page to select a gmail account to proceed with. Everything worked from there.

Comment: Hi, where is the folder on Windows? I need to delete the old tokens but I can't find the folder.